# How to select the field values as column names and rows using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have one table which contains multiple param name and param value.

[image]

[image]

I would like to select the records in such a way that all param name should come as header/column name and param values should get as multiple rows.

[image]

How to do it in mysql ?

Comment: If appropriate, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

use case when expression

```
select max(case  when param_name='school' then param_value end) as school,
max(case  when param_name='bus' then param_value end) as bus
from tablename group by test2_id
```

Comment: I already tried this, and its not working. I am getting 4 rows. one for each case condition

Comment: @Krish, I've edited it - you can check now

Comment: If I use max() it will give only one row but I need all records

Comment: @Krish, you can check now

Comment: How do you know which one's which?

Answer (score -1):

fa06's answer is probably the best way to make this type of selection if there is a known, static set of param_name values, for which case you can just hardcode them in. If not, you'd probably want to first select unique param_name entries and then a selection of the param_values for each different param_name.

Comment: can you please give me the sample query ?